# How I can skip step of jQuery Smart Wizard?

Tags: javascript, smart-wizard

I tried to skip step, but it doesn't work. I use this code:

`$('#wizard').smartWizard('goToStep', 3);`

in this code

```
} else if (stepnumber == 2){
    if (validate_step('#step-2-form')) {
       var form_data = $('#step-2-form').serializeArray(),
           value = form_data[0].value;

       // If owner have access to email, skip 3
       if (value == 'yes') {
           console.log('Skip 3');
           $('#wizard').smartWizard('goToStep', 3);
       }

       } else { isStepValid = false; }
           return isStepValid;
```

But I got circle:

[image]

But if I remove `$('#wizard').smartWizard('goToStep', 3);`, it's works fine.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop execution of the loop.

code will be,

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard('goToStep', 3); 

return false;
```